# adding multiple event listeners ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, iteration

I am trying to iterate an ajax query, yet whenever I try to run the code **i** always defaults to **1** I'm not very familiar with js and wondered whether anyone had any idea how to do this, or whether there is a better way to do it altogether. Thanks in advance!

```
$.each(Array(10), function(i) {
            var clickedButton = $('#' + (++i));
            $(clickedButton).click(function (){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'example.php',
                    data: {lightid: i},
                    success:function(result){}
                });
            });
          });
```

Comment: Your question is a little misleading - you aren't trying to iterate an ajax query, your goal is to attach a listener to a number of buttons that does nearly the same thing (just passing different data) - yes? If so, could you explain _what doesn't work_? "am not having much luck" doesn't give us much to go on...

Comment: It looks like you want to add an event-listener to a series of buttons. This is much easier achieved by using a class-based selector like `$('.clickbtn').click(...)`. An iteration is not necessary.

Comment: @chazsolo Hi, sorry for not being specific, I've updated the question hopefully that gives you slightly more of an idea as to what issues im having

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What is `numberlight`? I'd recommend adding a runnable snippet to your question.

Comment: @cars10m the problem with that is I need each event listener to send slightly different data depending on the button. This is why I have the **i** variable in the **data** section of my ajax query

Comment: @chazsolo im not sure how to add a runnable snippet, sorry! and numberlight was simply an integer, I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: When editing your question, there's a little icon that looks like a document with `<` and `>` in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using a `data`attribute with the necessary data for each "button". This can be picked out via `this.dataset.<attribute-name>` and sent to the server:

```js
$('[data-id]').on('click',function(){
 $.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',{lightid:this.dataset.id})
  .done(r=>console.log(r))
})
```

```css
div[data-id] {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click on any div below:</div>
<div data-id="1">one</div>
<div data-id="2">two</div>
<div data-id="3">three</div>
<div data-id="4">four</div>
<div data-id="5">five</div>
<div data-id="6">six</div>
<div data-id="7">seven</div>
<div data-id="8">oneeight</div>
<div data-id="9">nine</div>
<div data-id="10">ten</div>
```

I used the attribute `data-id` to hold the numerical information, as the html attribute `id` should always have values starting with an alphabetical character.